# Rails won't use sequence for primary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, primary-key, sequence

For one reason or another the pre-existing Postgres schema I'm using with my Rails app doesn't have a default sequence set for a table's primary key, so I am required to query for it every time I want to create a new row.

I have `set_sequence_name "seq_people_id"` in my model, but whenever I call `Person.new` Postgres complains to me because Rails is executing the insert query without the ID (which is marked as `NOT NULL` in the schema).

How do I tell Rails to always use the sequence when creating new records?

- Postgres 8.1.4
- ActiveRecord 3.0.3
- Rails 2.3.10

Comment: What version of Rails / Postgresql are you running? Also, which Ruby Postgres gem are you using to connect?

Comment: Postgres 8.1.4
ActiveRecord 3.0.3
Rails 2.3.10
pg 0.10.0

Comment: A bit unrelated: but you should try to upgrade to a supported Postgres version as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I get when I run psql and \d foo:

```
                                 Table "public.foo"


 Column |   Type        |              Modifiers                       
--------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------
  id    | integer       | not null default nextval('foo_id_seq'::regclass)
(etc.)
```

I'd check the following:

- Verify the actual sequence name is the same as what you reference (people_id_seq vs. seq_people_id)
- Verify the table's default is similar to what I have above
- (just checking) is the primary key's field named "id" ?
- Did you create the table using a migration or by hand? If the latter, try creating a table with a migration, specifying the same fields as in your people table. Does it work properly? Compare the tables.

Comment: The sequence name is correct. The column does not have a default nextval set in the schema. I don't have access to change the database.